# Extract number after $ sign regex

Tags: regex, excel

I have an excel function that extracts numbers from cells but I want to change the pattern to extract number after $ sign.

Number can range from 1-100000. It can have decimal points as well (ex. 1.1000). Numbers will never be negative. Number will always follow a $ sign.

Ex. `Text text $50.35`

I need to get `50.35`.

I need help writing the .pattern portion. I tried and keep failing.

Really appreciate your help.

Comment: is the content of the cells actually text or are they currency values?

Comment: You might try `(?<=\$)[1-9][0-9]*(?:\.\d+)*.?` It does start from 1 but it does not account for a max of 100000 https://regex101.com/r/ulbtml/1

Comment: Content of the cell is text.

Comment: Is anything else in the cell, other than the `$` and the numbers? in which case `SUBSTITUTE` would do the job

Comment: Are the numbers always last?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might match the dollar sign and capture the number in a group.

```
\$([1-9][0-9]{0,4}(?:\.\d+)?|100000(?:\.0+)?)(?!\S)
```

**Explanation**

- `\$` Match dollar sign
- `(` Capturing group

  - `[1-9][0-9]{0,4}` Match from 1 - 99999
  - `(?:\.\d+)?` Optionally match a dot and 1+ digits
  - `|` Or
  - `100000(?:\.0+)?` Match 100000 and optionally a dot and 1+ times a 0
- `)` Close capturing group 1
- `(?!\S)` Assert what is on the right is not a non whitespace char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OkjWIs/1)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that maybe this expression or a slight modified version of that might work here:

```
\$(10{5})$|\$([1-9]\d{1,4}(\.\d+)?)$|\$([1-9](\.\d+)?)$
```

In this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/oHRLxG/1/), the expression is explained, if you might be interested.

My assumptions are:

- We wanted to pass `$100000` and fail `$100000.0`.
- The strings would end with our desired numbers.